# Add additional matches to preg_replace_callback pattern

Tags: php, wordpress, pattern-matching

I'm editing a Wordpress script and this part excludes any content in a post between H tags from being linked. I want to make sure some other content between certain classes or tags are not linked either.

So the current code will only include anything between h tags 
but I need it to also match to anything between figcaption
tag as well. But I do not want to match to likes of p tags etc.

The script is adding links from a glossary and I do not want it to link headings and captions. I'm thinking I need another expression so it's match a OR b.

Here is an example of caption HTML

```
    <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">Anfisa prepares to</figcaption>
```

I have since tried this:

```
((<figcaption.*>)(.*)(</figcaption>)|(<h.*?>)(.*?)(</h.*?>))
```

But that seems to just be matching the first instance of either and then stopping. 
Thanks!

```
if ($options['excludeheading'] == "on") {

    $text = preg_replace_callback('%(<h.*?>)(.*?)(</h.*?>)%si', function($m) { 
    return $m[1].SEOAutoReSpecChar($m[2]).$m[3];
},
$text

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not be using regex to parse HTML content, especially if that HTML content be nested.  Instead, you should use some type of parser, which PHP has available.  But, if you want an exact solution with your current approach, we can try matching the opening tag, while capturing the tag's text.  Then, match the same closing tag afterwards.

```
$text = "<figcaption>blah</figcaption>";
$text = preg_replace_callback('%<([^>]+)>(.*?)</\1>%si', function($m) { 
    return $m[2];                         //   ^^^^ backreference
}, $text);
echo "The following text is contained within a single level HTML tag: " . $text;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim, I did not write the code I'm just trying to adapt it to suit. OK so that code you have supplied will match any tag right? I need to match several specific ones like the H1, H2, H3, H4, H5,H6 and <figcaption>. If that makes sense, the other ones I want to ignore.

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what the real problem is.

Comment: I've edited Tim, I don't want to match any tags just specific ones. So headings and captions, in this case.

Comment: @JamesWray Then you may slightly modify my pattern to search for specific tags.  But, in general, you should not use regex to parse HTML content.